# Conexión de Base de datos entre servidores Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, codeigniter, xampp

Tengo mi proyecto montado en un servidor con la `ip 10.45.16` ("SERVIDOR 1")  en ese servidor adema del `Sistema` tengo una base de datos en `MySQL`  y tengo otro servidor ("SERVIDOR 2") dentro de la misma red con la `ip 10.35.6.35` he intento hacer una conexión a la base de datos desde mi sistema que esta en el servidor 1 a la base de datos del servidor 2 pero me marca un error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/SIV_P1/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

Utilizo esta conexión:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '10.35.6.3',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'bd_prueba',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => TRUE,
    'compress' => TRUE,
    'stricton' => TRUE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

> La IP que agrego en el host es la ip del servidor 2
>
> Los datos como el nombre el usuario y la contraseña de la base de
>   datos están bien

Es posible realizar esa conexión y si es así como quedaría ya que no he descubierto como hacerla.

> Lo que intento hacer es dejar un servidor como servidor de BD y el
>   otro solo para las aplicaciones, utilizo `xampp` en ambos servidores

Comment: Hola, que estén dentro de la misma red no implica que los servidores de base de datos acepten conexiones desde "fuera" (otro server). Te invito a revisar esa configuración primero.

Comment: Y si este fuera el caso, ¿Se podría solucionar, que configuración tendría que hacer?

Comment: Si, se podría solucionar, pero tendrías que averiguar como "abrir" el servidor de la base de datos, pero primero debes validar eso revisando la documentación y el estado de tu base de datos.